# Security of perf under root access

Tags: sudo, perf

when I use perf it asked for more permission to be used:

You may not have permission to collect stats.

I was lazy so I did sudo perf (some short program I created myself) but I later realize you can allow perf a little more access that's is not root. My question is that is it secure to use the command:

```
sudo perf
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: "Secure" is not a clear term. You need to say *what* you want to secure *against what*; we really can't guess what you mean here!

Comment: @MarcusMüller Security in the sense of not leaking data to third party. I am afraid giving perf root access would compromise the security of my data. The program I asked perf to analyze is a short program I created myself.

Comment: Is the third party the party running perf?

Comment: @MarcusMüller I ran perf on terminal testing my own program (a short program).

Comment: so, who's the third party? Which privileges does it have? What kind of data are you afraid of leaking to it?

Comment: @MarcusMüller I only gave sudo rights to perf, but now I'm afraid that you are not supposed to give sudo rights to perf so I'm asking here to know if that was fine.